# Compile errors when building Cornerstone v4.3_r2.2

Tags: android, android-source, android-4.3-jelly-bean, multi-window

I'm trying to build this on my device, but I have some problems during the building process. First of all, I synced the AOSP 4.3_r2.2 source tree. Then I copied the entire cornerstone codes (from branch v4.3_r2.2) into the source tree. Then I start to build.

First, I got a lot of errors like these:

```
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:244: error: Symbol 'config_bluetooth_adapter_quick_switch' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:1558: error: Symbol 'config_enableDreams' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:919: error: Symbol 'ic_suggestions_add' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:920: error: Symbol 'ic_suggestions_delete' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
...
```

After compared a lot, I found lots of missing symbols seems only in public.xml. If I were right, I think these symbols should be defined in somewhere else, then be added into public.xml. So I just removed these by restore the public.xml to unmodified (git checkout).

And then when I ran building again, I got the error like this:

```
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/wm/DimAnimator.java:57: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable FX_SURFACE_DIM
location: class android.view.Surface
                        Surface.FX_SURFACE_DIM);
                               ^
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/wm/DimAnimator.java:54: internal error; cannot instantiate com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.SurfaceTrace.<init> at com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.SurfaceTrace to ()
                    mDimSurface = new WindowStateAnimator.SurfaceTrace(session, 0,
                                  ^
...
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/wm/DimSurface.java:48: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable FX_SURFACE_DIM
location: class android.view.Surface
                        Surface.FX_SURFACE_DIM);
                               ^
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/wm/DimSurface.java:45: internal error; cannot instantiate com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.SurfaceTrace.<init> at com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.SurfaceTrace to ()
                    mDimSurface = new WindowStateAnimator.SurfaceTrace(session, 0,
                                  ^
...
```

By looked into the AOSP source, I found the Surface.FX_SURFACE_DIM should be SurfaceControl.FX_SURFACE_DIM, and the WindowStateAnimator.SurfaceTrace constructor's parameter number is different. So I wonder whether am I use the "right" source tree of AOSP? If not, which version should I sync? Since there are so many differences than the codes in cornerstone.

Thanks.

Comment: @Dennis Kriechel although it contains some java code, this is not a java question, but rather one concerning version-to-version changes of the "we TOLD you not to link to those" internal details of AOSP.  If the original poster had put the java tag in it could stand, but it is really not the type of change for which an edit is warranted as the solution is neither going to come from the java community, nor will it be of interest to them.  Tags should reflect what a question is *about*, not what it *contains*.  Syntax highlighting is both irrelevant here, and achievable more directly.

Comment: you already posted this problem yesterday, and reposting is not allowed.